# Datetime format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a `DateTime` saved in `dtmNextPayment`. I want that to showed in the label in mm/dd/yyyy way. I have tried using

`lbltakeeffectdate.Text = dtmNextPayment.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");`

But month is always shown as 00. I have no idea why? Please let me know what should be the problem..

And also, please tell me what is the best solution.. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lbltakeeffectdate.Text = dtmNextPayment.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

[List of Format Options](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: @Greg - oops! Did a cheeky copy and paste from the OP.  thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Month is "MM". "mm" is minutes.

Full list of available custom datetime formats (along with examples) is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to use MM.  Capital M is month, little m is minutes